# IE asks for credential when try to download any file with anchor tag on production only

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

```
<a href="MainDetails/Documents/Setup%20cod.docx" title="Setup docs">Setup Docs
```

> The above code works fine in intranet, local and all browsers except IE, but in IE it prompts a login window and ask for userid and password if i cancel that even it downloads the file.

Any suggestion why this is happening?

Comment: which code?? i can't see.

Comment: <a href="MainDetails/Documents/Setup%20cod.docx" title="Setup docs">Setup Docs</a

Comment: It shows 3 options
1.Open
2.Save
3.Save As

it only asks for credential if user choose 1st option.

Comment: If you try from incognito mode in the browsers that work, would it still work? Missing/cached headers can cause these problems, or if IE thinks you don't have access to the folder where the file is stored for example

Comment: It is working fine with every browser it only ask in IE when try to open it instead of saving it.

Comment: Please suggest what cached headers you are talking about